# Silverlight DataContext: Changes also being made in Cloned Object

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, silverlight

Consider follwing method of copying/cloning an object (all fields are copied into a new object)

```
    public AangepastWerk CloneAdjustedWork(AangepastWerk pAdjustedWork)
    {
        return new AangepastWerk()
        {
            AangepastWerkID = pAdjustedWork.AangepastWerkID,
            ArbeidsOngeval = pAdjustedWork.ArbeidsOngeval,
            DatumCreatie = pAdjustedWork.DatumCreatie,
            DatumLaatsteWijziging = pAdjustedWork.DatumLaatsteWijziging,
            DatumOngeval = pAdjustedWork.DatumOngeval,
            GewijzigdDoor = pAdjustedWork.GewijzigdDoor,
            NietErkend = pAdjustedWork.NietErkend,
            Stamnummer = pAdjustedWork.Stamnummer,
            Verzorging = pAdjustedWork.Verzorging,
            VerzorgingId = pAdjustedWork.VerzorgingId
        };
    }
```

I have a form that opens up a childform where two objects (2 times the same object of the type mentioned above) is being passed. I open up the form like this:

```
                //my selected Record
                Record rec = DateGridAdjustedWorks.ActiveRecord; 
                AangepastWerk AWorkObject = (AangepastWerk)((DataRecord)rec).DataItem;
                AangepastWerk AWorkObjectBackup = _Vm.CloneAdjustedWork(AWorkObject);
                WindowModifyAdjustedWork windowForModify = new WindowModifyAdjustedWork(AWorkObject,AWorkObjectBackup, true);
                windowForModify.Closing += new CancelEventHandler(OnModifyAWClosing);
                windowForModify.ShowDialog();
```

In that childform I set the first object as DataContext. _adjustedWork and _adjustedWorkCopy are properties of the form

```
            _adjustedWork = pAdjustedWork;
            GridAdjustedWork.DataContext = AdjustedWork;
            _adjustedWorkCopy = pAdjustedWorkCopy;
```

**The Issue:**
In the form i have the ability to alter the object while retaining the original object. the user can see the originalobject, so he has the possibilities to keep track of the changes (request by the user) BUT if i change something in my _adjustedWork (the object that is my datacontext) then my _adjustedWorkCopy (without any actions performed upon it in my code-behind) is changed aswell. My question to you bright minds is: Why does this happen and how do i work around it? What am i missing here (probably something very basic)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the reason why the Cloned Object recieved the changes as well

```
public AangepastWerk CloneAdjustedWork(AangepastWerk pAdjustedWork)
{
    return new AangepastWerk()
    {
        AangepastWerkID = pAdjustedWork.AangepastWerkID,
        ArbeidsOngeval = pAdjustedWork.ArbeidsOngeval,
        DatumCreatie = pAdjustedWork.DatumCreatie,
        DatumLaatsteWijziging = pAdjustedWork.DatumLaatsteWijziging,
        DatumOngeval = pAdjustedWork.DatumOngeval,
        GewijzigdDoor = pAdjustedWork.GewijzigdDoor,
        NietErkend = pAdjustedWork.NietErkend,
        Stamnummer = pAdjustedWork.Stamnummer,
        Verzorging = pAdjustedWork.Verzorging, <------------ Issue lies here
        VerzorgingId = pAdjustedWork.VerzorgingId
    };
}
```

pAdjustedWork.Verzorging is an object in this case. I needed to clone this object aswell.I assumed (incorrectly) that cloning as above mentionned would create a new separate 'VerzorgingsObject'.

The solution to my problem is:

```
        MedicalCare_VM mcare_VM = new MedicalCare_VM();
        return new AangepastWerk()
        {
            AangepastWerkID = pAdjustedWork.AangepastWerkID,
            ArbeidsOngeval = pAdjustedWork.ArbeidsOngeval,
            DatumCreatie = pAdjustedWork.DatumCreatie,
            DatumLaatsteWijziging = pAdjustedWork.DatumLaatsteWijziging,
            DatumOngeval = pAdjustedWork.DatumOngeval,
            GewijzigdDoor = pAdjustedWork.GewijzigdDoor,
            NietErkend = pAdjustedWork.NietErkend,
            Stamnummer = pAdjustedWork.Stamnummer,
            Verzorging = mcare_VM.CloneMedicalCare(pAdjustedWork.Verzorging), 
            VerzorgingId = pAdjustedWork.VerzorgingId
        };
```

Cloning in:

```
         Verzorging = mcare_VM.CloneMedicalCare(pAdjustedWork.Verzorging)
```

uses the same logic as mentioned before (copying every field).

Answer (score 1):

I always do deep cloning with serializing to json.

In example with Servicestack you can:

```
var json = myObject.ToJson();
var clonedObject = json.FromJson<MyObject>();
return clonedObject;
```

Maybe this can help.

Comment: ServiceStack (w JSON) could provide me with a potential working solution. But i hoped to avoid the use of third party DLL's